# My dictionary is empty although it has values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have very strange issue I have dictionary with these values

```
NSDictionary * dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"usr_id",areaChoosedId,@"usr_adrs", _username.text ,@"usr_psd", _name.text ,@"usr_name",_mobile.text,@"usr_tel",_email.text,@"usr_mail",_password.text,@"usr_pwd",usr_ava,@"usr_ava", nil];
```

but when i print the dictionary it outputs that

```
{
    "usr_id" = 1;
}
```

although when i print the user name or mobile or email all have values and not nil so what is the problem?

Comment: Please put some more code. It is not feasible to identified from this chunks.

Comment: How and where are you creating the dictionary and logging it?

Comment: these values is refer to textfields in viewcontroller when i print my dicionary i dont find the other keys

Comment: NSDictionary * dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"usr_id",areaChoosedId,@"usr_adrs", _username.text ,@"usr_psd", _name.text ,@"usr_name",_mobile.text,@"usr_tel",_email.text,@"usr_mail",_password.text,@"usr_pwd",usr_ava,@"usr_ava", nil];
                             
    NSLog(@"%@",dic);

Comment: when i call action of button i make dictionary with these keys and valuse

Comment: please add more code. and make sure your dictionary is allocat or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this one. Seems that you  didn't get value of `areaChoosedId`.

```
NSMutableDictionary * dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
     [dic setObject:@"1" forKey:@"usr_id"];
     [dic setObject:areaChoosedId forKey:@"usr_adrs"];
     [dic setObject:_username.text forKey:@"usr_psd"];
     [dic setObject: _name.text forKey:@"usr_name"];
     [dic setObject: _mobile.text forKey:@"usr_tel"];
     [dic setObject: _email.text forKey:@"usr_mail"];
     [dic setObject: _password.text forKey:@"usr_pwd"];
     [dic setObject: usr_ava forKey:@"usr_ava"];
```

hope it works for you.

Comment: thank you very much all objects have values except areaChoosedId but why they didnt show other objects and keys and just show the user id

Comment: after getting null value , value  not store in dictionary using "dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys" this .

Answer (score 1):

It seems all your values are `nil`. Having the below code produces the same result

```
NSDictionary * dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @"usr_id",
                      nil, @"usr_adrs",
                      nil, @"usr_psd",
                      nil, @"usr_name",
                      nil, @"usr_tel",
                      nil, @"usr_mail",
                      nil, @"us‌​r_pwd",
                      nil, @"usr_ava",
                      nil];
NSLog(@"%@",dic);
```

Logs

```
{
    "usr_id" = 1;
}
```

From the docs

> If any key is nil, an NSInvalidArgumentException is raised.

So there is no check for the `nil` value

**NOTE:** After the first `nil` value it will stop reading next `key/value` pair

Comment: The keys being `nil` have nothing to do with this. No keys are nil here. `areaChoosedId` and maybe even some of the subsequent values are `nil`, and the argument list of `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` is nil-terminated so it stops reading after the first nil **value.**

Comment: thank you very much i understood now why it shows user_id only

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant No keys are `nil`, the value are `nil` and you are right after the first `nil` value it is not reading the next values